# What to do with a dead Gateway 30" LCD Monitor?

Tags: lcd

Someone gave me a dead gateway 30" monitor  (apparently the XHD3000 has a remarkably high failure rate - usually a month or two after the warranty expires).

It can't be serviced - no one will fix it.   Does anyone have any creative ideas as to what I can use this thing for?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? No backlight, no picture, bad picture, no power?

Comment: bad picture.  search youtube for xhd3000 problems.  common problem.  logic board failure = thing is a brick

Comment: Sorry, but you said it yourself. Short of taking it apart for fun, its a brick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shoot it at the gun range.  Post a video on youtube

Comment: interesting.  Should we go with something large caliber?  hollow point? Deer Slugs?

Comment: Man, take and some pictures and send them to time warp.  Tell them they should try it with running LCD monitors so we can see the carnage in slow motion.  Don't forget to post some pictures!

Answer (score 3):

Sell it on ebay for parts, you might not get much for it but someone else might have a similar monitor but with a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the sound of it, the lcd portion might be good or bad. Personally, I would take it apart and see how it is put together.  Strip it down to the lcd and all the parts involved. I would use it as a learning project.

Or if you feel like making a dollar, there might be a chance someone is looking for the backlight or some other part.  Obviously, the common part dying would be the most desired though.  You have no invested $$$ into though, so I would take it apart.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly creative, but somewhere near you there'll likely be a place that can arrange for electronics to be broken down and sold to recycling companies. If you Google "electronic recycling [place name]" you should find something.

Otherwise: coffee table, picture/montage frame, kids' "I'm on TV" toy...

Comment: I like the kids "im on tv" toy.  Just make sure is just the frame and no internals. There are a lot of sharp edges.